# Prove that $l^2$ is a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I'm coursing an introduction to Hilbert spaces and I recently saw in the book "A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics" by P. Szekeres a proof that I don't completely understand.

The aim is to prove that $l^2$ (the set of all complex sequences where $u_i \in \mathbb{C}$ such that

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |u_i|^2 < \infty$

) is a Hilbert space. It begins showing that this space is linear and has a well-defined inner product. But then this comes:

[Quote:](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZuIgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA331)

The norm defined by this inner product is

$||u|| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |u_i|^2} \leq \infty$.

For any integer $M$ and $n,m > N$

$\sum_{i=1}^M |u_i^{(m)} - u_i^{(n)}|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |u_i^{(m)} - u_i^{(n)}|^2 = ||u^{(m)} - u^{(n)}||^2 < \varepsilon^2$,

and taking the limit $n \to \infty$ we have

$\sum_{i=1}^M |u_i^{(m)} - u_i|^2 \leq \varepsilon^2$.

[In the limit $M \to \infty$](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZuIgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA332)

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |u_i^{(m)} - u_i|^2 \leq \varepsilon^2$

so that $u^{(m)} - u \in l^2$. Hence $u = u^{(m)} - (u^{(m)} - u)$ belongs to $l^2$ since it is the difference of two vectors from $l^2$ and it is the limit of the sequence $u^{(m)}$ since $||u^{(m)} - u|| < \varepsilon$ for all $m > N$. It turns out, as we shall see, that $l^2$ is isomorphic to most Hilbert spaces of interest - the so-called $\textit{separable Hilbert spaces}$.

Unquote

The problem that I've found is why he can assure that the sequence has limit $u_i$: is it an assumption or has it to be proved? I don't really understand how the last paragraph concludes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of the proof you are showing is that one that proves that $u$ is in $\ell^2$. Before that, in a part you are not quoting, the author likely deduced that
$$
|u^{(m)}_i-u^{(n)}_i|\leq\|u^{(m)}-u^{(n)}\|_2.
$$
This shows that for each $i$ the sequence of *numbers* $\{u_i^{(m)}\}$ is Cauchy. Because $\mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb R$, depending on what the author's choice is) is complete, there is a limit $u_i=\lim_m u^{(m)}_i$. Then comes the part of the proof you quoted, that shows that $u$ is in $\ell^2$ and it is the limit of $\{u^{(m)}\}$ in the $\|\cdot\|_2$-norm.

Comment: 1) I testify the quote was faithful and complete. Sadly, the author deduces nowhere that $
|u^{(m)}_i-u^{(n)}_i|\leq\|u^{(m)}-u^{(n)}\|_2.
$ He even doesn't explicitly begin his proof with something like "let $(u^{(n)})$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\ell^2$. For all $\varepsilon>0,$" 2) The quote mentions the choice of $\mathbb C$ (not $\mathbb R$). 3) The previous example of Hilbert space in this book was $\mathbb C^n$ but I have no access to that page. In view of the quote, it may also be that his *(sketch of)* proof of completeness for $\ell^2$ rather relies on that for $\mathbb C^M$.

Comment: Well, I know nothing else about the book, but if that's the case then it is very poorly written.